PowerShell, how to copy files with totals and log in file
In PowerShell I use the following to copy all directory contents, including subdirectories and files.
copy-item -Path $source_folder -destination $onedrive_folder -force -recurse

How can I write a list of all files and subdirectories copied?
Do I need to write a for statement, as I have read in some posts. I searched and some posts in PowerShell have written a for statement for all files copied with a counter.

Add -Verbose parameter to your Copy-Item command? Please edit your question to provide more details on what you expected to happen versus what actually happened. This will help readers figure out what didn’t work and how to answer your question accordingly. See also: how to ask

You can use the parameter -PassThru to, basically, enable the output of Copy-Item: it will now output the object representation of each newly copied item.
Then you can pipe it through Select-Object to strip the object down to only its full path.
Then pipe that to Add-Content which, as suggested by the name, will append the received values to the file you decided to use a log file.
Copy-Item -Path $SourceDirectory -Destination $DestinationDirectory -Recurse -Force -PassThru |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName |
    Add-Content -Path $logFile

If you need more\different information than just the full path, you can play with calculared properties.
Evaluate using Export-Csv if you need many properties
